# What's the difference between expensive and cheap SQL Server backup products?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I'm looking for SQL Server database backup solution and I have found many third party tools. But their prices vary greatly. For example, SQL Backup from RedGate or Idera costs about $900 - $1000 while SQLBackupAndFTP or SQLBackupMaster costs about $70. What's the reason? Does it mean that RedGate's or Idera's products are more than ten times better than the cheaper ones? Or they more reliable? They all do what I need (e.g. make schedule backups, store them somewhere and notify me by email), but I'm just  completely disorientated with such ten-times price difference. Do I miss anything?

Comment: Having used the products, RedGate's backup is fast.  It's a lot faster than the native SQL backup.  It was explained to me once, but I've forgotten.  Something about not taking all of the transactions I believe.  I would suspect (but don't know for certain) that the less expensive options use the native backup commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you need to pay for a backup solution?

I think '**free**' is always a good contender - [Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) maintenance scripts are used by a LOT of people.

Simply schedule them using the SQL Agent.

Comment: I think one of the reasons people want a backup tool is to make restores easier. That's something Ola's scripts are lacking.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik dbatools.io's `Restore-SqlBackupFromDirectory` cmdlet can help with that